# PYTHON IN MAYA : get theline with warning

Tags: python, maya

I would like to know how I can get the line of the warning when I use `pymel.core.warning()` (or `maya.cmds.warning()`).

I try to add the argument `showLineNumber = True` but nothing changed. I only have got this warning : `# Warning: The 'showLineNumbers' flag is obsolete and will be removed in the next version of Maya. Use the Script Editor checkbox to turn on line number display instead. #`

I check on /History > line numbers in error/ and /Command > show line number/ but nothing changed.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal in the sense that Maya isn't helping all that much, but something like this should work, and relies solely on Python.

```
import inspect
maya.cmds.warning(
    'Line number is: {}'.format(
        inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).lineno
    )
)
```